# Rails callback executed after all fields have been initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

How can I create a callback in the model which gets called after all the fields have been initialized?

I tried using an `after_initialize` callback like so:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :print_self

  def print_self
    pp self
  end
```

However, at this time all fields are `nil`, as ilustrated by the print statement:

```
#<Article:0x007f8bea51a298
 id: nil,
 name: nil,
 body: nil,
 url: nil,
 published_at: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 guid: nil,
 summary: nil>
```

Comment: Where is the model getting initialized and how are you initializing it?

Comment: Also, please keep in mind things like 'ids' are not initialized until you actually save the model.   Initialization simply assigns the values you specify to the attributes you've created and not model keys or foreign keys.

Comment: I am initializing it with `FactoryGirl`, by calling `FactoryGirl.create`

Comment: Would you mind posting that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

The callback you have created in the above code is correct.   The issue I see here is that I don't see any code for initializing the model such as 'new', which will assign values to your attributes.

In the absence of this, none of your attributes have any values.

You may ask, why does 'id' not have a value, but this is because ids are only created and assigned when a record is actually created/saved.

You need something along the lines of:

```
Article.new(:name => 'My Article')
```

in your controller or just go to the rails console and do the following:

> > article = Article.new(:name => 'My Article')

to initialize an Article.